# eclipse JSP line wrapping

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

In Eclipse, I've setup the Java formatter to wrap lines only when they exceed 120 characters. I would like the same setting to be used when I format JSP files, but at the moment it wraps them when they exceed 90 characters, is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Window - Preferences - Web - JSP Files - Editor. Click on the link for your kind of JSP (HTML or XML content), and adjust the line width.

Answer (score 4):

Note in the latest version of eclipse you won't see the line width option in jsp files editor, instead this is covered by the line with setting in html files - editor menu

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Preferences -> type HTML...You'll see "Editor" so in line width, enter the value as you need. Works for me on eclipse 2018-12 version